# Diferença de chamar uma função na DllMain por CreateThread ou chamando de forma direta

Tags: c, c++, windows, thread, dll

Qual é a diferença de chamar uma função das seguintes maneiras:

A primeira maneira criando uma thread.
Exemplo:

```
DWORD WINAPI Metodo1(LPVOID)
{
      // Meu código aqui...
      return NULL;
}

int WINAPI DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
     switch(dwReason)
     {
     case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
          CreateThread(NULL, NULL, &Metodo1, NULL, NULL, NULL);
          break;
     }
     return true;
}
```

Segunda maneira chamando de forma direta no Main.
Exemplo:

```
void Metodo2(void)
{
    // Meu código...
}

int WINAPI DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
     switch(dwReason)
     {
     case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        Metodo2();
        break;
     }
     return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É uma péssima prática fazer chamadas de `API` dentro da `DllMain()`!

A função `CreateThread()` é uma das únicas funções que podem ser chamadas dentro da `DllMain()`, porém, isso deve ser feito com bastante cuidado pois essa prática facilmente pode causar `dead-locks` no seu programa.

Toda vez que o programa que utiliza a `DLL` é executado/finalizado ou quando uma `thread` é disparada/finalizada, o código da `DllMain()` é executado, por esse motivo as operações realizadas por ela devem ser cuidadosamente avaliadas.

Afinal, qual é intento de disparar uma `thread` dentro da `DllMain()` ?

Referências:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040127-00/?p=40873

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688290/creating-a-thread-in-dllmain